# How can I load in real time with Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a problem.

I want to use spinner when listing data with **Vue**. But not by giving **setTimeout**, I want the text loading to appear during the actual loading of the data and unload when the browser completes the loading process.

How can I do that?

```
// Project List
getAllList: function(){
setTimeout(()=>{
 axios.get('api.php')
 .then(function(response){
            //console.log(response);
            app.listContent = response.data.listPro;

      });
}, 2000)

},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a loading progress of data fetching.

- // 0 = not started
- // 1 = loading started
- // 2 = loading completed  without problem
- // 3 = there is a problem.

in data define a process prop.

```
data(){
   return {
      loading: 0
   }
}
```

then you can use the loading in the method.

```
getAllList: function(){
 this.loading = 1 
 const self = this
 axios.get('api.php')
 .then(function(response){
    app.listContent = response.data.listPro;
    self.loading = 2
 })
 .catch(err => {
    self.loading = 3
 })
```

if you don't want to reach data object by using `const self` then use `() =>`

```
 axios.get('api.php')
 .then((response) => {
    this.listContent = response.data.listPro;
    this.loading = 2
 })
```

if `loading == 2` then show the text. if not then handle it differently...

Comment: It detects loading 1 but does not go to loading 2.

Comment: I also added the version of `this.`